# Build a "driver-based" model in Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to build an eloquent model "Platforms" that can implement some logic in the same way as driver-based components.

A little generic background:
I have a laravel model called Platforms, that has some generic methods. But depending on the exact "platform", i would like to build some custom methods, that is only usable for that specific platform. It could be like a connection method or similar.

So my approach was to do like the driver based components, that extends the `Illuminate\Support\Manager` because i need some kind of contract on the methods. And i would like the methods to be accesable when i have loaded the specific "platform".

I know that i can just write each method in the model itself, or include like a handle method for each platform. In the end i will have around 10 platforms, with around 5 custom methods, so it will get ugly really fast.

I would prefer not to build it as a component, because i need the relationships to other models.

Another way of explaining it could be like this:
Say you have a bunch of users that can get SMS notification from an app, the user can then choose which SMS "provider" the have to use. (ei. like Nexmo) This would then be a `class SMSProvider extends model` 
which have certain methods like `send`
That way you could do `$user->SMSProvider->send()`

This send method would have to be specific to the specific provider, just like in the documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/notifications#sms-notifications

Can you give me some pointers as to which way i should look or code?

Comment: What if you will have for example Platform model in the "app/Models/" and in "app/Models/SubPlatforms/" you will have some specific platforms?? In this case you can write some core functionality only in Platform model, and other specific functionalities for each models. That child models will be as extended models from Platform. What you think about this..

Comment: I'm thinking a similar solution would be easier and just create a generic method of mapping the type of the platform to the classes that implements it? As i see this question it is more about code separation and cleanliness than anything else?

Comment: How would it then "load" the specific subPlatform. In my example i always load the platform through a relation, like ```$user->platform->specificMethod()```?

Comment: I will make an answer tonight :) i can probably also make it work with the Manager class.

Comment: @mrhn Any progress on a possible answer?

Comment: Oh sorry totally slipped, will make some examples :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing the answer i would have to assume a lot about the solution. The basis is set, you need an Platform model assume it has a type indicating the provider.

```
/**
 * @property string type
 */
public class Platform extends Model
{
    ...
}
```

The driver approach is mainly done if external people should extend your library and is a sort of managing tool for different implementations. That is not wrong, but i feel like it is more complicated than it should be. The straight forward approach would to bind the types of the platform to an implementation. Create an interface for the implementation.

```
public interface SMSProvider
{
    public function sendSMS(): void;
}
```

For shows sake, an implementation.

```
public class TeliaSMSProvider implements SMSProvider
{
    public function sendSms(): void
    {
        // magic
    }
}
```

In your app service provider, bind you type to the application.

```
$this->app->bind('telia', function ($app) {
    return new TeliaSMSProvider();
});
```

Again this binding part is just an easy way to make the connection between the type and the correct instance, driver or method calls based on the type parameter could have been done.

Now just load your provider from the platform, with the type as the input. Typehinting for easier to work with.

```
public class Platform extends Model
{
    public function getProvider(): SMSProvider
    {
        return app($this->type);
    }
}
```

Comment: So in order to use the custom methods, i would do something like:

Comment: $platform = Platform::find(1);

$platform->getProvider()->sendSms();

There is an implication that you have some sort of type column that indicates what sms provider you want to use.

Comment: sorry got distracted, my editing time window passed. Is there a way to "autoload" the methods, when the model has been loaded?

Comment: you can override the call method, or create a helper in platform.

Public function sendSms() {
    $this->getProvider()->sendSms();
}

Comment: use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model as MysqlModel;
use Basemkhirat\Elasticsearch\Model as EsModel;

class BaseModel extends EsModel{

}

how we can change dynamically extend derive in Laravel model?? In this case, in configuration, we use elastic search if we want to change the driver to MySQL we need to manually change the driver? is there any way to change it from configuration ?